# libwebsockets.h - no such file or directory, Ubuntu, arm-linux-gcc cross compiler

Tags: c, gcc, arm, cross-compiling, header-files

I am building a web server using the libwebsockets library on a TS-7800 board using the arm-linux-gcc cross compiler. Using Ubuntu. Installed CMake, OpenSSL, and libwebsockets and built the library per the instructions on Github.

I made a "hello world" C file which #includes libwebsockets.h
When I compile the executable with gcc, it compiles fine and the .exe runs.
When I compile with arm-linux-gcc, I get the following:

```
root@gordon-MS-7A39:/# arm-linux-gcc -o hellosockets /home/gordon/workspace/HelloCrossWorld/hello_cross.c
/home/gordon/workspace/HelloCrossWorld/hello_cross.c:3:27: libwebsockets.h: No such file or directory
```

It appears that arm-linux-gcc compiler cannot "see" the header file for libwebsockets. I'm guessing that the installation of the websockets library was successful because gcc can see it.

**How do I enable the arm cross compiler to see the libwebsockets.h file?**

Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unaware of the -I and -L preprocessor options for gcc and arm-linux-gcc.
I was able to add libraries to the project and will look into creating makefiles for the project.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add *armhf* architecture to your package management system. Perform the following actions as super user:

```
dpkg --add-architecture armhf
apt update
apt install libwebsockets-dev:armhf
```

Make sure you're also using the armhf toolchain:

```
apt install binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

Alternatively, take a look at [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/)

Comment: Thanks, but some of the packages were not installed (404 not found) and Linux was unable to locate the package "libwebsockets-dev:armhf. I will take a look at Buildroot.

Comment: @Gordon I've tried this in Debian 9, but AFAIK it should be similar in Ubuntu. Have you run `apt update`? It could explain, why some packages could not be found.